# Class exists but it still can't find class in while running laravel migration

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, data-migration

This is the migration code but it gives this error
( Class 'Modules\RolePermission\Entities\InfixPermissionAssign' not found )
I have checked the names everything is right and the path is also correct appreciate your help.
I have copied this code from another project it was working there. Everything is same here too but still it doesn't work here.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Modules\RolePermission\Entities\InfixModuleInfo;
use Modules\RolePermission\Entities\InfixModuleStudentParentInfo;
use Modules\RolePermission\Entities\InfixPermissionAssign;

class CreateInfixPermissionAssignsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('infix_permission_assigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->tinyInteger('active_status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('module_id')->nullable()->comment(' module id, module link id, module link options id');
            $table->string('module_info')->nullable();
            $table->integer('role_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('infix_roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('saas_schools')->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable()->default(1)->unsigned();

            $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable()->default(1)->unsigned();

            $table->integer('school_id')->nullable()->default(1)->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('sm_schools')->onDelete('cascade');
        });


        // for admin
        $admins = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 533, 534, 535, 536, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 537, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 538, 539, 540, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570];

        foreach ($admins as $key => $value) {

            $permission = new Modules\RolePermission\Entities\InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 5;
            $permission->save();
        }

        // for teacher
        $teachers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 533, 534, 535, 536, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 537, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567];

        foreach ($teachers as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 4;
            $permission->save();
        }

        // for receiptionists
        $receiptionists = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 65, 66, 67, 83, 84, 85, 86, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 188, 193, 194, 195, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 553, 554, 560, 564];
        foreach ($receiptionists as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 7;
            $permission->save();
        }


        // for librarians
        $librarians = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 61, 64, 65, 66, 67, 83, 84, 85, 86, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 188, 193, 194, 195, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 553, 554, 560, 564];
        foreach ($librarians as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 8;
            $permission->save();
        }

        // for drivers
        $drivers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 188, 193, 194, 19, 553, 554, 560, 564];
        foreach ($drivers as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 9;
            $permission->save();
        }

        // for accountants
        $accountants = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 83, 84, 85, 86, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 188, 193, 194, 195, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 553, 554, 560, 564];

        foreach ($accountants as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 6;
            $permission->save();
        }

        // student
        for ($j = 1; $j <= 55; $j++) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $j;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 2;
            $permission->save();
        }
        $students = [554, 555, 559, 564];
        foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 2;
            $permission->save();
        }

        // parent
        for ($j = 56; $j <= 96; $j++) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $j;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 3;
            $permission->save();
        }
        $students = [554, 555, 560, 559, 564];
        foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
            $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();
            $permission->module_id = $value;
            $permission->module_info = InfixModuleInfo::find($value)->name;
            $permission->role_id = 3;
            $permission->save();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('infix_permission_assigns');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload` to clear out the cache? That sometimes helps me. Sometimes generating classes with the `make` command automatically flushes the cache, but afterwards edits don't get picked up.

Comment: trying right now.

Comment: This line: `$permission = new Modules\RolePermission\Entities\InfixPermissionAssign();` shouldn't be this?: `$permission = new InfixPermissionAssign();`

Comment: it didn't work...

Comment: Actually it was like this: $permission = new InfixPermissionAssign(); but it didn't work and gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the namespace and the permission of the file? Make sure the namespace and permission and owner of the file is correct. In my cases, sometimes both of those problem were the one when everything just 'seems' to be in order.